# getAdmin is not function when using reverse association

Tags: node.js, express, node-orm2

**models association:**

```
Entity_Department.hasOne('entity', db.models.entity, {reverse: 'entity_departments'});  

Entity_Department.hasOne('entity_location', db.models.entity_locations, {reverse:'admin'});
```

**server side controller:**

```
Entity_Location.get(entity_locations_id, function(err, entity_locations){

    entity_locations.getAdmin(function(err, departments){

        for(var i = 0; i < departments.length; i++ ){
            departments[i].ede_is_deleted = true;
            departments[i].ede_updated_at = new Date();
        }
```

It shows that `getAdmin()` is not a function. The same concept is working for other models, so where am I going wrong?

Comment: please answer my question anyone ........its urgent

Comment: Have you found any solution...?? I'm facing the same issue...